# Call custom block on Success Page Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I need to call a custom block on success page

I have tried by layout as mention below

```
   <checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml" >
                <block type="core/template" name="birthday" template="checkout/message/birthday.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>
```

In success page

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('birthday');
```

I am getting birthday block twice on the page.

Please let me know how we can call custom block on success page.

I don't want to use dynamic block i.e.

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')
->setTemplate('checkout/message/birthday.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the `birthday` block twice because of this line from success.phtml:

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
```

This line renders all child blocks of the main block.
If you want it listed only once remove the line

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('birthday');
```

It will be redered by the `getChildHtml` method anyway.